# vscode: ConfigurationChangeEvent : how to know the change is user or workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to know the change is global or workspace, is  there any method ?

I wang to listen the configuration change, i find the ConfigurationChangeEvent, but it seems can not know it is a user configuration change or a workspace configuartion

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [`vscode.WorkspaceConfiguration.inspect`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration.inspect)

This will give you all parts separate.